# Get activity instance from called activity

Tags: android

I have an activity containing some fragments. One of those fragments calls another activity. In this new activity I need to have an instance of the first activity. GetParent() returns null so I don't know how I can acomplish this...

**MainActivity** --contains--> **Fragment1** --startActivity()--> **SecondaryActivity**

Is there some way to get the calling activity on the SecondaryActivity?

Comment: No you should not do that. Each activity has a lifecycle.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think there is a good way of doing so.
It's really a bad practise to handle activity references like that, since android wouldn't be able to gc them when needed (orientation changes, lack of memory).


The best way is to pass all the data you need with `Intent` extras (intent that you use to start activity), and, if you need **SecondActivity** to return something, use `Fragment1.startActivityForResult()` for starting activity, and when done, use `SecondActivity.setResult()` to return desired result, you will need to override `onActivityResult()` to get the result (there are plenty tutorials about this).


If you absolutely need to hold references to something, you can use your own instance of `Application` class (don't forget to declare it in the manifest) to hold data for you while application is running.